# can I trigger SimpleButtonAction?

Tags: java, swing, jmenuitem

I have a menu bar with many SimpleButtonAction. Some of them need to show if they are pressed or not (for example, the "show grid" button).

I have looked for this feature, but I am not an englishspeaker and I don't even know if this is called "triggering" or anything else.

I found JToggleButton, but it can't be added to a menu bar into a bibliothek.gui.dock.DefaultDockable.

Any hint so I can search better for some info?

Comment: Sure, i meant that sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JCheckBoxMenuItem ? JToggleButton?

Comment: as I said, JToggleButton has no add method. But I'll totally have a look at the JCheckBoxMenuItem, thanks :)

Comment: Totally right. My problem now is the dockable not accepting this kind of buttons, but that's a different problem. Thanks! :)